# Backbone fetch and reset model when model added to collection

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, backbone-model

I have a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jrsalunga/8D22N/26/)

That contains a model

```
Item = Backbone.Model.extend({....})
Apvdtl = Backbone.Model.extend()
```

and a collection

```
Apvdtls = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Apvdtl
})
```

and populate the collection with Apvdtl Model
e.g.

```
apvdtls.add([{ itemid: 'c4676cef679a11e28b7a3085a942bd8e', qty: 10 }, 
             { itemid: '1da17339690f11e285d63085a942bd8e', qty: 5 }])
```

and generated this view

[image: grid1]

but what im trying to do is to is to make a view like this

[image: grid2]

by fetching the Item with ID on this [JSON File](http://sjcs.herokuapp.com/api/item)

```
ApvdtlView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'tr'
    initialize: function(){
        this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
        this.template = _.template('<td><%=itemid%></td><td><%=qty%></td>');
    },
    render: function(){

        item.set({'id': this.model.get('itemid')});
        // item = {id: 'c4676cef679a11e28b7a3085a942bd8e'}

        item.fetch(); // but this doesnt get the data
        // this should contain this data after i fetch 
        // item = {"id": "c4676cef679a11e28b7a3085a942bd8e",
        //         "code": "prp125", "descriptor": "Paper", "price": "7.00"}

        // build new data to render
        var data = {
            "itemid": item.get('descriptor'),
            "qty": this.model.get('qty')
        }

        this.$el.html(this.template(data));
        //this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First **Ajax is Async** . So you never know when the response comes back, so it is better to attach it to an event.

```
ApvdtlView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'tr',
    initialize: function () {

            // This listens to the sync and change event and renders the item
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change sync', this.render);
        this.template = _.template('<td> <%=itemid%> </td>' +
            '<td><%=qty%></td>');
        this.model.fetch();

    },
    render: function () {

        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});
```

Next `url` property has to be set for the Model `ApvdtlView` as that is being fetched from the server.

Next is you cannot hit this url from your domain

```
urlRoot: 'https://raw.github.com/jrsalunga/prism2/master/www/api/item.json'
```

as it is a different domain as it violates the cross origin policy. You need to use `jsonp` to get this

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/8D22N/21/)**

**[JSONP request Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/8D22N/23/)**

Now you can see the data that is fetched in the network tab but throws an error since the callback has to be handled serverside

Comment: Thanks for the answer! =) but my view(`ApvdtlView`) dont need url because im just using it to render for may "data" from the collection(`Apvdtls`). regarding the url `https://raw.github.com/jrsalunga/prism2/master/www/api/item.json` im just trying to "get the data there" and not intended for saving. The data for view(`ApvdtlView`) is from two model: the model(`Item`) and from this code `apvdtls.add([{ itemid: 'c4676cef679a11e28b7a3085a942bd8e', qty: 10 }])` so i just build a new dataset for my view(`ApvdtlView`) not to my 'ApvdtlView`'s model(`Apvdtl `)